# jQuery select divs that dont have a class containing a particular word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of divs, some of them have the class 'layers-widget-...', others just have different classes.

I want to select all the ones that don't have the class 'layers-widget...' and add the class "hidden" to them.

I have been able to select all the ones that have the class using the following script:

```
$('#available-widgets-list div[class*="layers-widget"]').addClass('hidden');
```

How would I essentially do the opposite though to select ones that don't have the class.

Comment: Try this: `$('#available-widgets-list div:not(".layers-widget")').addClass('hidden')`

Comment: @SandeepNayak Your solution is not completely right. the code you offered only selects divs that does not have class exactly equal to '.layers-widget'. What he asked for was select divs that their class does not contain the string '.layers-widget'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
$('#available-widgets-list div:not([class*="layers-widget"]')).addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: You're welcome. If helped, Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :not() selector like this:

```
$('#available-widgets-list :not(div[class*="layers-widget"])').addClass('hidden');
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwPqLy